# Add class to HTML input to create animation using EJS, Express, and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, function, express, ejs

I'm trying to animate a form by making the name of my inputs slide from my input box to a position above my input box.

Its been a while since if used EJS so I apologize in advanced if this is silly. I've searched just about everywhere and nothing is working! This is also my first time asking a question here!

Problem:
I'm unable to access the document of my EJS file from my app.js. Below is the code I'm trying to implement. I cant, for the life of me, figure out how to make this work in EJS.

JavaScript:

```
// Custom Order Page
app
  .route("/custom-order")
  .get((req, res) => {
    
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input");

    function focusFunc() {
      let parent = this.parentNode;
      parent.classList.add("focus");
    }

    function blurFunc() {
      let parent = this.parentNode;
      if (this.value == "") {
        parent.classList.remove("focus");
      }
    }

    inputs.forEach((input) => {
      input.addEventListener("focus", focusFunc);
      input.addEventListener("blur", blurFunc);
    });

  res.render("custom-order");
  })
```

This is the EJS file code:

```
  <div class="contact-form">
    <form action="/custom-order" method="post" autocomplete="off">
      <h3 class="info-title">Contact us</h3>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="input"/>
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <span>Name</span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="input" />
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <span>Email</span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="tel" name="phone" class="input" />
        <label for="">Phone</label>
        <span>Phone</span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container textarea">
        <textarea name="message" class="input"></textarea>
        <label for="">Message</label>
        <span>Message</span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input class="input" type="file" id="formFileMultiple" multiple>
        <label for="formFileMultiple" class="form-label">Reference Images:</label>
        <span>Images</span>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

And this is the CSS related to the focusing:

```
.contact .input-container.focus label {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 25px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.contact .input-container.focus span:before,
.contact .input-container.focus span:after {
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: It won't work because you are trying to access the DOM from inside an express route handler. There is no `document` and you should be getting a `ReferenceError`. You need to have that code in some `<script>` tags in your ejs template file or linked in an external js file using `<script src="file.js">` tag.